# What does the title of "Code 8" refer to?

Tags: title, code-8

There is a movie called [*Code 8* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6259380/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). I watched it thoroughly and I can not understand where the movie's name comes from.

What does "Code 8" refer to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The movie you saw was based on a short film released in 2016, also called [*Code 8* (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5574166/).  In this movie, one mutant (for lack of a better term, we go with Marvel Comics' definition) throws a brick through a car window and he and a fellow mutant are then hunted by police for committing a "possible Code 8".  In the ensuing confrontation with police, one mutant clearly uses his powers to injure an officer.  At that point, the police broadcast that "a Code 8 has been committed".

It can therefore be inferred that Code 8 is the "police code" for a mutant using his powers to commit a crime.